# Como extraer un numero de una cadena casi aleatoria en C++ usando expresiones regulares

Tags: c++, string, regex

Como extraer un numero concreto de un `string` que puede tener casi cualquier forma, me explico:

Mi string puede ser: `cualquiercosa+CH+number+cualquiercosa`
es decir: `TEST-13?:41CH12f:A1345`

Solo necesito extraer el numero que sigue a CH y convertirlo a `int`.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Podrías explicar que has intentado para resolverlo? Con algo un poco especifico seria una buena pregunta.

Comment: De momento, aclararme con que libreria usar. Finalmente debe ser boost/regex ,no puedo usar la estandar por limitacion en la version de gcc 4.4.7.

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que estas en Stack Overflow, el cual a diferencia de sitios como Yahoo Respuestas, no es un sitio donde preguntes algo y esperes ayuda sin siquiera mostrar algo de codigo, algo de esfuerzo, para asi poder ayudarte, **muestranos que has hecho, que errores tienes durante el proceso, muestranos el codigo,** para asi poder ayudarte efectivamente.

Comment: @user2357667 te comento que seguimos otro mecanismo en el sitio. No es un lugar donde uno pida código y se lo escriban (no es un reemplazo de Google), sino que esperamos que muestres qué estás intentando, dónde estás teniendo problemas, qué problemas específicos, y recién ahí ver posibles respuestas concretas. Quizás te sea útil realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Si se te ocurre cómo modificar tu pregunta para seguir estos lineamientos, encontrarás el enlace a [edit] debajo de tu pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

El formato de la cadena parece bastante cerrado pese a la *aleatoriedad* de la misma, las siguientes expresiones te pueden servir para extraer el número:

- `.+CH(\d+).+`.
- `\w+-\d+\?:\d+CH(\d+)f:.+`.

Según lo restrictivo que quieras ser deberías usar una u otra.

#### Aplicar expresión regular a texto.

La cabecera [`<regex>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) añadiada a C++ en el estándar C++11 automatiza el proceso de usar expresiones regulares:

```
std::regex expresion(R"(\w+-\d+\?:\d+CH(\d+)f:.+)");
std::cmatch coincidencias;
std::regex_search(texto, coincidencias, expresion);
```

Tras la llamada a [`std::regex_search`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) el objeto [`std::cmatch`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results) (que es una versión de `std::match_result` para cadenas de caracteres `char`) contendrá el texto capturado de la expresión regular, estando la primera captura en la posición 1.

#### Transformar texto a número.

Puedes usar la función [`std::atoi`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) de la cabecera [`<cstdlib>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdlib):

```
int numero = std::atoi(coincidencias[1].str().c_str());
```

La función `std::atoi` espera recibir un puntero a una cadena de caracteres. El operador corchetes (`[]`) del objeto `std::match_result` devuelve un objeto [`sub_match`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/sub_match) que tiene una función para convertirse a `std::string`.

Pero yo prefiero la opción de usar un [stream de texto](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
std::stringstream stream(coincidencias[1].str());
int numero = 0;
stream >> numero;
```

#### Código.

[[Aquí]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QH9O90GNpCxCrffm) puedes ver el código funcionando:

```
int main()
{
    constexpr char text[]{"TEST-13?:41CH12f:A1345"};
    std::regex expresion(R"(\w+-\d+\?:\d+CH(\d+)f:.+)");
    std::cmatch coincidencias;
    std::regex_search(text, coincidencias, expresion);

    std::stringstream stream(coincidencias[1].str());
    int numero = 0;
    stream >> numero;
    std::cout << numero;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Me quedé pensando: ¿por qué usaste `constexpr` y no simplemente 
`const`?

Comment: ¿Y por qué no? Ese texto es una expresión constante.